# jquery-3.2.1.SLIM.min.js TypeError: self.$dropdown_content.stop is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, selectize.js

I noticed that jquery-3.2.1.SLIM.min.js throw an error (TypeError: self.$dropdown_content.stop is not a function) when is used in Angular 2 project width selectize.js 
What is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use selectize.default.css-> everything ok
Use selectize.bootstrap3.css -> throws error 'TypeError: self.$dropdown_content.stop is not a function' on any change of dropdown

Solution: change to jquery-3.2.1.min.js

That may save someone hours...